# Pair Permutation of the set of Natural Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Given the set of natural numbers $N$ is it possible to preform a series of operations that would result in a set with all of the different permutations of pairs? Something like: $$\{\{1,1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},...\{2,1\},\{2,2\},...\}$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "a series of operations"?  Are you looking for a function that takes a number $n$ and gives the $n^{th}$ sequential pair?

Comment: Yes, exactly a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new set $ S $ such that

$S=\left \{ \left \{ a, b \right \}\mid a, b \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot!